# how to implement master detail layout using ionic 3 and split pane component?

Tags: angular, ionic3, splitpane

I am new to Ionic 3. Can someone please explain how to implement master detail layout using ionic 3 and split pane component? If you can show with some working example it will be very helpful.

Comment: I want to use Ionic3 with angular 4 not angularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the Ionic Docs? And google examples?

https://alligator.io/ionic/split-pane/

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/